EventID 1002 When Microsoft Store Updates Application, using C++ MFC
I have a C++ MFC application, which hangs when the application is updated via the Microsoft Store. After the update the application is not running.
How can I ensure the application keeps running after the update.

Any ideas on how to simulate the update process, i.e. send windows messages to the app / other api calls etc.*

I assume the application got blocked in the main UI thread (which is odd, since the application was fine while not updating);
Steps to reproduces:

Start the application on Windows 10
Open "MS Store" and go to "Library", click "Get Updates"

Results:

The application is running while updates are downloading
The application is terminated, and the application is not restarted.
I get the following entry in the Windows EventLog:

Log:
  - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  - <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Hang" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>101</Task> 
    <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-05-20T20:18:03.1169635Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>6018</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>win10</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
    </System>
  - <EventData>
    <Data>App.exe</Data> 
    <Data>1.0.0.1</Data> 
    <Data>289c</Data> 
    <Data>01daa70704524710</Data> 
    <Data>4294967295</Data> 
    <Data>C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\....</Data> 
    <Data>some guid</Data> 
    <Data>....</Data> 
    <Data>App.exe</Data> 
    <Data>Quiesce</Data> 
    <Binary>510075006900650073006300650000000000</Binary> 
    </EventData>
    <

I am wondering what the MS Store App uses to terminate the application? My application does intercept WM_CLOSE, which is used to minimise to the system tray.
Then I tried seeing if the application would get Hanged by calling the windows IsHungAppWindow() together with simulating a bad WiFi using Parallels "bad network" setting, which is really bad.
Here is the code I used for testing the app, which reports the that app is not hagning. "many dots printed on the screen".
  #include <iostream>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include "Tchar.h"
  #include "winuser.h"
  
  #include <chrono>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <thread>
  
  int main()
  {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    HWND h = ::FindWindow(NULL, _T("AppWindowName"));
    if (h)
    {
        std::cout << "Found Window!\n";
        while (true) {
            BOOL r = IsHungAppWindow(h);
            if (r == TRUE) {
                std::cout << "app hang detected!!\n";
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << ".";
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);}
    }
  
      std::cout << "End!\n";
  }


I have a VM with a copy of the old app installed on Windows 11 (not the actual Windows 10 issue, but hoping it behaves the same), ... this gets me closer to debug it, but now I need a version of SPY++ for Windows ARM64 - which does not exist ?

The update (and communication) is probably controlled via the Restart Manager API (as opposed to sending arbitrary messages to arbitrary application windows). The packaging system is involved, too. What packaging system are you using and are you doing anything funky with the Restart Manager from your code?

Hi @IInspectable, I am using the Windows Application Packaging Project  MSIX, also I am not doing anything with the "Restart Manger" - Perhaps I should be doing something, implementing something to gracefully exit the application ?

It looks like I need to do something.. since I do intercept WM_CLOSE.
I should Implement this: Applications should shut down only when they receive the WM_ENDSESSION message

Correct, It's a hang, in as far as the installer has requested that you close and you have not responded to the request in a timely manor. Implement both the restart manager AND WM_ENDSESSION.

Ading Restart Manager support is easy, just follow the guide
